# Rails 3 - Using .find for a record whose class is unknown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, find

Being new to RoR, apologies for my vague phrasing of the question.

So I'm trying to make a custom validator, like so:

```
class MyValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    ...
  end
end
```

I want to check if certain attributes of the record already exist in my database. How do I use `.find` here - I can't use it with `record`. How do I access the function then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

uniqueness validation you can use `validate_uniqueness_of`

to obtain the record's class, you can use `record.class` and then `record.class.find`

Comment: Thank you, record.class was what I was looking for

Comment: sounds like validate_uniqueness_of is really what you were looking for based on the description. let rails do the work for you.

Comment: Well, my model has a first name and a last name. I'm validating the [case insensitive, so I can't use scope] uniqueness of the full name.